# Cellular components of blood cells

Tags: hematology

There are different types of blood cells in the human body i.e. red blood cells, neutrophils, basophils, eosinophils, monocytes, T-cells, B-cells.

What are the cellular components of these cells? What are the organelles that are found in these cells? I can't find this information anywhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's pretty straightforward.  White blood cells have all the usual organelles while mature red blood cells are missing most of them.  WBC can have *specialized* lysosomes depending on their function, as well as granules if they are granulocytes.

Comment: I edited to remove a sentence with a dead link that had no attached information to find out what is was.